# Is it required to register and pay Adobe for learning PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova, adobe, cloud

Do I really need an account on Adobe to learn PhoneGap. Is it possible to create the application and test it on my PC

Comment: I suppose the course you are taking is going to teach you how to use phonegap build, for phonegap build you need an adobe account, but you can create it for free. See the available phonegap builds here https://build.phonegap.com/plans

Answer (score 0):

No you don't! You can download it, code, deploy, run, and publish to the store without permission!

And for the history and relation between Cordova, PhoneGap, Apache, and Adobe you can [check this out](http://phonegap.com/2012/03/19/phonegap-cordova-and-what%E2%80%99s-in-a-name/).

Answer (score 0):

Nope, I don't think so. Even though PhoneGap was recently acquired by Adobe, it looks like the platform itself is still up for individual download. Have you tried checking out [the official installation guides](http://phonegap.com/install/)?

It looks as simple as using Node's package manager:

```
sudo npm install -g phonegap
```

Comment: I join a course from LYNDA and its saying in the beginning of course that i need to have an account on adobe creative cloud. Its charging monthly.

Comment: No, that's not the case. The course might be covering other things involving Adobe Creative Cloud, but it's not expressly required.